# why does css displays in style tag in the head of react rendred html when i inspect

Tags: css, reactjs

my component :

```
import React from "react";
import "./homepage.styles.scss";

const Hompage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="homepage">
     .......

    </div>
  );
};

export default Hompage;
```

Style file:

```
.homepage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 80px;
}

.directory-menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

when i inspect my code  it displays as  `<style>  my css </style>` int the head

here is a picture of  what displays in chrome devtools:
[image: here is a picture of what displays in chrome devtools]

Comment: It's probably injected via a web pack setting this way

Comment: I guess your classname is wrong, className="hompage" should be className="homepage"?  You imported a scss file in your react file, so is completely normal show the css there.

Comment: i generated a new app  using create-react-app but still  have the same issue, how can i avoid that ?

Comment: Ênio Abrantes   :  style is working  but when i inspect  it displays between <style> tags in the head

Comment: What is the actual issue?  I know why it's doing that (it's optimizing the loading speed), but why are you trying to avoid it?  It should be working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal or general or common way that the react /angular apps are bunduled into. Where you get all the css and js put into a single index.html page.

You can't avoid it i assume.

But try with lazy loading components but still i think the css would be appended previously into your page.

The css and js are compiled and appended into a main html file so that the browser doesn't have to make a request and wait until it finishes.

1)  This way your page will load fast.
2)  A server request would be saved.
3)  No blocking  css or js.
4) and many more ....

Benefits you get using webpack to do this

Even the css library that you are going to use all are appended into a style tag in your page